# Devexpress: How to add a control to below the other control in XtraReport

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtrareport, devexpress-windows-ui

I use `XtraReport` to show my report. I want to add my chart to below the other one. Here is my code to add a new chart on `XtraReport`.

```
foreach (Control viewControl in Panel.Controls)
{
    if (viewControl.GetType() == typeof(ChartControl))
    {
        XRChart chart = new XRChart();

        ChartControl chartControl = viewControl as ChartControl;

        if (chartControl != null)
        {
            foreach (ISeries series in chartControl.Series)
            {
                Series s = new Series(series.Name, ViewType.Bar);
                s.Points.Add(
                    new SeriesPoint(
                        series.Points.First().UserArgument.ToString(), 
                        series.Points.First().UserValues.FirstOrDefault()
                    )
                );
                chart.Series.Add(s);
            }

            myReport.Detail.Controls.Add(chart);
        }
    }
}
```

I could not find the way to insert a break line between two `XtraChart`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to indent your charts by using [`XRControl.TopF`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXRControl_TopFtopic) property. The value of indent you can get from the [`XRControl.BottomF`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXRControl_BottomFtopic) property of previous chart.
Here is example:

```
float topF = 0;

foreach (Control viewControl in Panel.Controls)
{    
    var chartControl = viewControl as ChartControl;

    if (chartControl == null)
        continue;

    var chart = new XRChart();

    foreach (ISeries series in chartControl.Series)
    {
        var s = new Series(series.Name, ViewType.Bar);
        s.Points.Add(
            new SeriesPoint(
                series.Points.First().UserArgument.ToString(), 
                series.Points.First().UserValues.FirstOrDefault()
            )
        );
        chart.Series.Add(s);
    }

    chart.TopF = topF; // Indent chart.
    topF = chart.BottomF; // Set next value to the topF.

    myReport.Detail.Controls.Add(chart);    
}
```